# How to Extract Path of Controller Function in Express.js

Tags: javascript, express, url, routes

In Express.js, from an app, you can extract the name of all controllers. Though, the name comes in a strange form (e.g. handle: [AsyncFunction: login]). I cannot find a way to destructure this which could potentially give the filepath.

If this is a dead end, is there any other way to extract this information from from the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the filepath, why not using the available native `__dirname` (Ecmascript) or `import.meta.url` (CommonJS) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I integrate the Ecmascript into the answer?

Comment: `__dirname` woks as an environment variable. You can use as such, globally

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the question. I'm tring to extract the pathname of the controller from the express app.